# How to declare __m128i constant in MASM?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, sse2

```
align(16)
__xmm@200020000a4f0a4f6621662170707070 xmmword 200020000a4f0a4f6621662170707070h
```

and

```
__xmm@200020000a4f0a4f6621662170707070 xmmword 0x200020000a4f0a4f6621662170707070
```

Both fail, the compiler saying `error A2138: invalid data initializer`

Comment: If all else fails, use two 64 bit initializers with `DQ`.

Comment: @Jester Thanks, it works but inconvenient to use, I have to write `xmmword ptr [__xmm@...]` in every place where my code uses the value.

Comment: @Jester Neither `0`, `0x0`, nor `0h` work. Only `0.0` and `0.0f` do. Multiple floating point values work too. Surprisingly, even more than 4 values work, have no idea why you’d want more than 4 values, it’s a 128-bit data type.

Comment: @Soonts: With more than 4 values, you're defining an *array* of `xmmword`s, just like `dd 1,2,3,4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best workaround I found is to use two 8 byte initializers with a separate `LABEL` definition, such as:

```
__xmm@200020000a4f0a4f6621662170707070 LABEL xmmword
dq 0x6621662170707070, 0x200020000a4f0a4f
```